# Android Studio runs multiple already-deleted devices when running the AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

when I run my AVD from Android Studio it also runs devices I already deleted in the past. It also sets an "IDE error accurred" message.

I tried deleting *.lock's, setting a new device, re-installing the IDE, using other versions and many more things but nothing seems to work on my issue.

Any idea how to solve it?

[I can't post images so here's a link of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPoEp.png)

[List of AVD's from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry4tY.png)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

So I was able to fix that if anyone would ever need.

1. I deleted the device i was using.
2. I closed the Android Studio.
3. I deleted the .android folder completely.
4. I opened the Android Studio and created a new device. (don't run yet)
5. I went to **Settings > Tools > Emulator** and set off 'Launch in a tool window'.

Now everything works just fine.